Cypress Videos so low resolution I cannot read any text
We have some Cypress E2E tests running in Github Actions. After a test run, we upload failed tests into artifacts
Unfortunately, the resolution of the video is so low. These are my settings
export default defineConfig({


e2e: {
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.ts',
    setupNodeEvents,
    viewportHeight: 1600,
    viewportWidth: 2560,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 20_000,
  },
  projectId: 'gpqaaf',
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  reporter: 'mochawesome',
  video: true,
  videoCompression: 1,
  reporterOptions: {
    configFile: 'reporter-config.json',
  },
  retries: {
    runMode: 0,
    openMode: 0,
  },
});

I recently added VideoCompression: 1 and I do not think it made a difference, previously this param did not exist
I've added a screenshot of the .mp4 file that I am viewing in VLC to illistrate how bad it is. The text on our actual application is mostly unreadable.
Any suggestions?


I should add when you inspect the properties of the mp4 file, it says the resolution is 1280x580. This resolution is not specified anywhere in code

Have you read e.g. https://www.cypress.io/blog/generate-high-resolution-videos-and-screenshots? Increasing the viewport size will actually make it appear smaller in the video, as the actual browser size isn't increasing.

HelloJonrsharpe, Yes I reduced it down to 1920x1080 and it had no positive affect
